# Why is there no "aggregate" function (only reduce) on a non-windowed datastream?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm new to Apache Flink. I'm confused why there isn't any `aggregate()` transformation for non-widowed datastreams. I only have `reduce()`. So, for now, my workaround has been to call `map()` just before the `reduce()` and to use `map` to create an accumulator of size 1 (ie essentially, the element I wish to add); then, the `reduce` function essentially does what the `merge` function in the normal aggregate would do, but this is potentially not very efficient. Is there a good workaround?

Comment: Is there some aggregation you can't do using the `reduce()` operation?

Comment: You can use AggregatingState in a KeyedProcessFunction if you like.